# How to auto submit using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, oscommerce

I have oscommerce based website. The product's attributes are read from text file. All i want is to press the "insert product" button automatically either through AJAX or anything else. So that i can add 100 product daily in automatic way instead of manually uploading them using text file and press "insert product" button 100 times.

Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Have you considered using an OSCommerce "Import from text file" extension?

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you stuck at where to begin? Please update your question to indicate one or the other :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

```
formObject.submit()
```

or

```
buttonObject.click()
```

how to access the both objects I cant tell you without seeing the markup.

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not a javascript. I have found the solution. I need to add such products directly into the database using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Products are different from product attributes. You can simply use a script to upload the products. You can upload the images using an ftp before upload just to make sure the product images are shown up well in the product display.

Shiva